# Is it possible to track a file from inside .hg directory inside hg?

Tags: mercurial

I would like to know if it could be possible to add a file like `myrepo/.hg/info.txt` and track it with hg.

Why? I want to add an `hg` extension and keep it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Mercurial is very careful not to track its own files and that is defined as all files inside `.hg/`.

You need to put the extension into another repo and ask the users to clone this along with the main project.